# Prove that every rational solution of $x^n=c$ is integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Prove that every rational solution of $x^n=c$ is integer
>
> $c,n\in \mathbb N$

**My start:**

Let $x=u/q\quad \text{ such that } \gcd(u,q)=1$

$$\left( \frac u q \right)^n=c $$

I realy don't understand what should I prove here, since $c\in \mathbb N$ so $q$ must be equale to $\pm 1$, I can't find a formal way to show that.

Comment: Why must "q be $\pm 1$?" That's assertion. Mathematics is proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Suppose not, the result will give $c\notin \mathbb N$

Comment: $\frac{8}{2}=4$ is an integer, but $2\neq 1$.  Why is it not possible for $\frac{u}{q}$ to be not an integer but $\frac{u^n}{q^n}$ be an integer. Again, this requires proof.

Comment: But assumed that $\gcd(u,q)=1$ and $\gcd(8,2)\neq 1$

Comment: Of course, but you still haven't proved that $c=\pm 1$. You have to make an argument. If $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number, then there'd be some $p/q$ with $p^2/q^2=2$. Asserting this isn't possible because $q$ would have to be $1$ is assertion, not proof. The theorem is true, so I can't give you an example where it is false, but this does not mean you have given a clear mathematical argument. $a/b$ is often an integer when $b$ is not $1$. What is is about $u^n/q^n$ that lets you conclude that $q^n$ must be $1$?

Comment: The key to the proof is that if $u,q$ are relatively prime, then so are $u^n$ and $q^n$. This can be proved in a number of ways, but again, it requires mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $u^n=cq^n$, thus $q$ divides $u^n$,thus a prime $p$ which divides $q$ divides $u$. This implies $p=1$ since $u$ and $q$ are relatively prime, henceforth $q=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $c=1$, then $u^n=cq^n$ implies $u^n=q^n$ and so $u=\pm q$ and $q=\pm\gcd(u,q)=1$.

If $c>1$, let $p$ be a prime divisor of $c$. Then $u^n=cq^n$ implies that the exponent of $p$ in $c$ is a multiple of $n$ and so $c$ is an $n$-th power, $c=d^n$. Then $u=\pm dq$ and $q=\pm\gcd(u,q)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists a rational solution $x$ which is not an integer such that $x^n=c$, let $x=\frac{p}{q}$, where $p\in Z$ with $p\neq 0$, and $q\in N$ with $q\geq 2$. Then we may let $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and then
$$c=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^n=\frac{p^n}{q^n}\quad\mbox{or}\quad
  p^n=q^nc,$$
whcih follows that $q^n$ divides $p^n$, thus $2\leq q^n=\gcd(p^n,q^n)=[\gcd(p,q)]^n=1^n=1$. This gives a contradiction.